# boto3 cannot import name copy

Tags: python, boto3, aws-cli

I installed boto3 few weeks ago and all worked fine until now
tried to reinstall pip, reinstall boto3,reinstall aws cli, update machine (yum update) but nothing helped

```
 File "./get_reports.py", line 4, in <module>
    import boto3
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto3/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from boto3.session import Session
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto3/session.py", line 17, in <module>
    import botocore.session
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/session.py", line 25, in <module>
    import botocore.configloader
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/configloader.py", line 19, in <module>
    from botocore.compat import six
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/compat.py", line 172, in <module>
    import xml.etree.cElementTree
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/xml/etree/cElementTree.py", line 3, in <module>
    from _elementtree import *
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name copy




aws --version
aws-cli/1.15.3 Python/2.7.5 Linux/3.10.0-693.17.1.el7.x86_64 botocore/1.10.3
```

Same error when using botocore

code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python


import boto3
import json
import csv

client = boto3.client('iam')

response = client.get_account_authorization_details(


)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your version of boto3 is probably not the same as botocore

try running

```
pip freeze| grep boto
```

If the versions are different run

```
pip install --upgrade botocore
pip install --upgrade boto3
```

Comment: already tried that-no success, my script was in `/media` folder, once i ran script from different partition all started working ?????

Answer (score 0):

By any chance do you have a copy.py file in your current directory ? Try renaming it, if that's the case